# Deserializing json payload with double quote in a field

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson

I have an endpoint I've created via Jersey through Java that accepts a json payload. Jackson deserializes the json payload to a bean instance.

When a string field has a double quote in it, I'm getting a JsonParseException.

Working: `{"key":"value"}`
Not working: `{"key":"double \" quote"}`

I did some research and saw that double quotes were supposedly escaped in json payloads with a backslash, which is what I'm doing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. Show us the actual JSON string. And show us the parse exception stack trace.

Comment: I am using the jackson ObjectMapper class to serialize an instance of an object to a json string. The output string, for a particular string value, contains the backslash and double quote. Does this help?

Comment: No. Give us a clear and reproducible example. Also show us the stack trace.